# Notifications when new RSS is available

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss, notifications

I've created an app that displays an RSS feed.
I wonder if it is possible to get a notification when a new rss update.
Do I have to use push notification? (have heard that it is difficult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, push notifications are the way to go. It's not that complicated but you need some infrastructure on your side.

You'll need a server with a database that stores all the push notification recipients.
If you only have one hardcoded RSS feed just send a notification to all your clients if a new item is available.

If one can add own feeds to the app you need a database which saves the subscribed feeds for each push notification recipient. Then you have to check for new feed entries and send out notifications to the devices that are subscribed to that feed.

There are plenty of tutorials for push notifications out there. Both server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the user base of your app, urbanairship.com is probably the easiest way to implement push in your app. With them they handle all server side pushes and you can send a million free push notifications a month.

So if you add their codebase to you app, you can send 200000 users upto 5 notifications a monthm each.